# is elastic search works perfectly with windows

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

Actually i installed elastic search in my windows its installed perfectly but the problem is with starting of elastic search

when i enter command in CMD : `service start`

> Error : could not start JVM to detect version defaulting to x86 Failed
>   starting 'elasticsearch-service-start-x86' service'

```
C:\elasticsearch-2.1.1\bin>service install
```

> Warning: Could not start JVM to detect version, defaulting to x86:
>   Installing service      :  "elasticsearch-service-x86" Using JAVA_HOME
>   (32-bit):  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65;" Failed installing
>   'elasticsearch-service-x86' service

Comment: Most likely a JVM/Java Problem. What does `Java -version` output in CMD?

Answer (score 1):

Have you properly configured the environmental variable for the JVM. On my system I had to manually enter the entire path and could not use a `'~'` in the pathing. The error indicates that the JVm can't be located or loaded.

[This link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) covers the configuration of the environmental variable